# Double slit - missing part in usual description

Tags: quantum-mechanics, interference, double-slit-experiment

In double slit experiment there is usually explanation, where image particles create is different when both slits are open (A), compared to situation where only one slit is open, and then only another slit is open (B). What I always miss is clarification:

Is there any position on the screen that any particle hit in either test case (A) or test case (B) that couldn't be hit in the other test case, or the opposite is true: area of the screen hit by the particles is the same in both (A) and (B), only difference is pattern of probability distribution. Intuitively perhaps, (A) can affect larger area of the screen then (B), but is it true?

Comment: Maybe studying this will help http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/phyopt/sindoub.html

Answer (score 0):

When we calculate the interference pattern for both slits open, what we get is the probability *distribution* of measuring a particle somewhere on the detector. This distribution is zero in some places. However, in practice, every detector will have a finite resolution, so it will measure a particle whenever it hits some finite area (like a pixel). To get the probability for each pixel, we must integrate the probability distribution over the whole area of each pixel. Since the distribution is only zero in infinitely thin strips, the integral for any pixel will always have some finite probability greater than zero.

So while the *distribution* is zero in places for both open slits where it is large for only one open slit, the probability of detecting a particle is not zero anywhere.

That said, of course there are areas where fewer particles hit with both slits open than with only one open slit. That's why you see a different pattern in the first place. And by conservation of total probability, there must also be areas where there are fewer particles with only one open slit, compared to both slits open.

---

*Edit for now deleted comment*

The actual distribution for a single slit with width $a$ is
$$ I(\theta) = I_\mathrm{max} \left(\frac{\sin(z)}{z}\right)^2$$
where
$$z = \frac{\pi a \sin(\theta)}{\lambda} $$
with $\theta$ the angle from the central beam and $\lambda$ the de Boglie wavelength. For a double slit with separation $d$ it is
$$ I(\theta) = I_\mathrm{max} \cos^2\left(\frac{\pi d \sin(\theta)}{\lambda}\right) \cdot \left(\frac{\sin(z)}{z}\right)^2. $$
So you see that the double slit intensity (or probability density) is the same as the single slit intensity, but modulated with a faster oscillating $\cos$ term. Therefore, they will make the same overall (single slit) pattern, but the double slit has more sub-structure with bright and dark fringes within that pattern. This means the area covered in both cases is the same.

It is also worth noting that there is no *hard limit* to where the particles can land. The probability tends to zero the further away from the center we go, but doesn't reach it. So there is no hard limit to where they can in principle be detected, if your detector is large enough. This makes the whole question a bit ill-posed, because in both cases, there are no finite areas anywhere on the whole screen that cannot theoretically receive particles.

Comment: OK, I see, particle can reach anywhere on the screen for both cases. I wish this was emphasized in usual representations of double-slit experiment. Instead, it is usually illustrated in a misleading way, where one test case ends up inside very different area, compared to other.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by that. [Here](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Single_slit_and_double_slit2.jpg) are two photos of actual diffraction patterns. They look a bit different due to the different intensities, but you can clearly see they follow the same overall pattern, with the double slit having more fringes within that pattern. You can also see that they fade quickly as we go further from the centre, but they don't have a hard edge we could use to determine where exactly they stop.

Answer (score 0):

Photons hit everywhere across the screen. A light experiment with millions of photons will produce interference with dark areas. If the experiment is one photon at a time and you’re  looking at the results of a true experiment, then you will see photons impacts everywhere.  Instead of dark spots you will see areas of reduced impacts up to 50% less.